# What does this error: Static Resource named UploadTemplate does not exist

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

Hi am getting this error on my VF code, now only i started learning VF. Can anyone tell does it mean

> Error:Static Resource named UploadTemplate does not exist

Comment: It means exactly what it says: somewhere in your code, you are referencing a Static Resource, named UploadTemplate, and that static resource does not exist. You need to either create the resource or delete the reference.

Answer (score 1):

As novice visualforce developer i would first check the documentation, it is realy good:

[Using Static Resources](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm)

- Creating a Static Resource
- Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup

The second think i would check is the simple research in internet:

[Referencing an image static resource](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Referencing-an-image-static-resource/td-p/290885) 
[Setting up jQuery with salesforce.com](http://www.tehnrd.com/setting-up-jquery-with-salesforce-com/) 
[Delivering Static Resources with Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce)

Good luck.